# IE9 error , argument not optional

Tags: internet-explorer-9

when a button is clicked it invokes a JavaScript function .. this operation works fine in all browser except IE9. It throws error as argument not optional when the button is clicked. Here is the js function that throws the error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function removeFilter() {
    setFormAction('select_a_Form', 'path') && submitForm(document.select_a_Form, '_optionRemove');
    return false;
}
</script>
```

- `setFormAction` function gets the form name and action path from here and sets the action of the form to this value
- `submitForm` method submits the value `_optinRemove` to a hidden input variable in the form.

What makes IE9 to not recognize this I could not resolve . Should I include any IE specific loop? what makes IE9 to interpret this in a different manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the js error - The problem was with the function name `removeFilter()`. This function is not getting executed when called in IE9.

IE9 internally may use this function it seems , though i'm not able to get a proper proof of it to say.

When I changed the function name everything works fine.

The same issue was discussed in MSDN forums:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/iewebdevelopment/thread/8045c14a-464b-4cd1-83c6-f5885a8f9098